# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException on Android 9

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-9.0-pie, google-pixel

My app is live and getting crashes of "**Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException:**" from Google Play Console.

Mostly it is occurring on Android 9 OS and 50% of all devices on which it is coming are Google Pixel devices. I tried with other devices which are having android 9 but no luck.
I do not have Google Pixel device. Kindly anyone suggest me anyway to fix it or reproduce it.

Comment: Iam having the exact same issue for Android 9

Answer (score 0):

i dont know the reason this happens but you can use firebase test labs to reproduce this error. It contains several devices with several sdk versions including google pixel. Hope this helps.